# Topology of Liouville Numbers

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, liouville-numbers

Liouville numbers are defined as the numbers $x\in \mathbb R$ s.t. for ever $i\in\mathbb N$ there exist $n,m\in\mathbb Z$ such that
\begin{equation}
0<\left|x-\frac nm\right|<\frac1{m^i}.
\end{equation}
and they have the property of being well approximated by a sequence of rationals. Is there a (translation invariant) topology on $\mathbb R$ such that the closure of $\mathbb Q$ are the Liouville numbers?

Or maybe an uncountable set included in the Liouville numbers? The problem is always that such topology, if exists, cannot contain any ball.

Comment: I added translation invariant, otherwise one could just take the topology of the balls intersecated with the Liouville numbers

Comment: The metric for the balls is translation invariant.

Comment: That's trivial: let $\mathbb Q$ and the Liouville numbers inherit the usual topology, then define discrete topology on the rest of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin It is not translation invariant.

Comment: Darn! Indeed, a shift by $\sqrt2$ will turn some open sets into not-so-open.